# Bootstrap Responsive Navbar for Phones and other devices

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

This is the website I am working on.

http://ankursinha.net/TestSite/index.php

It's stacking up properly, it's responsive, everything is fine apart from the following.

When I visit this site from my phone or tablet, the navbar shows 3 lines, I click that and all the links show up, and then when I click the "LOGIN", it drops down and shows me Faculty Log In and Student Log In, but when I click one of these, it toggles and closes the dropdown thing.

I know this is happening due to:

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"
```

But how do I fix this and make it like a proper link to navigate through the site on smartphones and tablets? All the browsers had the same problem!

I checked with Responsinator and the same problem occurs there also.

Thank You

Comment: just to help out in other parts: **1)** move all scripts to the bottom; **2)** use `.hidden-phone` and `.hidden-tablet` to hide the entire header as it takes a lot of space when seeing from a mobile device; **3)** add the search inside and move the `home` link to the site name; **example**: http://jsbin.com/igadov/1/edit

Comment: Just tried your code, it toggles and closes back bro :(

Comment: **this was not an answer** to your question, it's a simple "help out" doing better. see the example link and check the `<header>` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed by adding (replace) this piece of code on **bootstrap-dropdown.js** (at the end of the script) :

```
$(function () {
  $('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
  $('body').on('click.dropdown touchstart.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
           .on('click.dropdown.data-api touchstart.dropdown.data-api'  , toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
           .on('keydown.dropdown.data-api touchstart.dropdown.data-api', toggle + ', [role=menu]' , Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
 })
```

Basically stops the touch event on a dropdown from bubbling to the next element, which would be the HTML tag and has the clearMenus function.

Comment: I am using the bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js, the minified versions that is, shall I add this anywhere? Or Shall I just paste this code before the closing body tag within script tags and check out?

Comment: add it on bootstrap-dropdown.js. You need to replace the snippet code.

Comment: Replaced it with that last snippet like you said. Responsinator shows that everything is fine but it's not coming properly on any of my mobile browser :|

Comment: Okay, replacing doesn't work. Rather I added it after the existing code. Worked like a charm. THANKS A LOT! :D

Comment: Adding that code gives rise a new problem. My dynamic dropdown gets disabled. Here is the link. It's not working. http://ankursinha.net/TestSite/upload.php