# Dynamic Dropdown List not working because of dropdown script

Tags: php, html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

This is the problem I had initially. 
[Bootstrap Responsive Navbar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215577/bootstrap-responsive-navbar-for-phones-and-other-devices)

Then I got the solution which "wandarkaf" posted. It worked fine and solved my problem.

Now my problem is, I have a dynamic dropdown file upload system for my site. It works perfectly on localhost but not on webserver. I realized, the dropdowns in the second and third level do not appear because of the dropdown script I added to overcome the mobile navigational dropdown issue. Removing that solves the current problem but gives rise to the previous problem. And solving the previous problem gives rise to the current problem.

How do I solve both of them and make things work.

Here is the link for my file upload: [Dynamic Dropdown File Upload](http://ankursinha.net/TestSite/upload.php)

It's supposed to work like this: [Example](http://ankursinha.net/upload.php)
Choose the Computer Science Engineering Option! The others have been disabled by me.

Please help me overcome both the problems. Thank you.

Comment: You've included bootstrap.js twice (dev and minified version).  And for some reason clearMenus() isn't defined.

Comment: Also jquery 1.8.2 and 1.8.3 are included....choose one!

Comment: @shapeshifter: I added the normal and the min file both. I guess they are slightly different? Not quite sure. And yeah I removed one of the jquery like you said. And clearMenus() probably not defined because of that snippet posted in that other stackoverflow link? Could you please see that code? May be you can understand, I couldn't try to solve it after playing around for 30 min

Comment: They are essentially exactly the same, you only need one though.  I'd include the not minified version while in development.

Comment: Okay, I will remove that too. But that still doesn't solve or gives the slightest hint to solve my problem. I googled about the clearmenu thing you spoke about, not much help.

Comment: You've done your $(function () {
    $('html').... calls outside of the plugins scope.

Comment: Okay, so where do I put it to solve both the problems?

Comment: Also you've include the bootstrap css twice.  Go for the unminified versions in development.

Comment: While the duplicates shouldn't really cause any issues, its not a good thing to be including them twice regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
}(window.jQuery);

$(function () {
  $('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
  $('body').on('click.dropdown touchstart.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
       .on('click.dropdown.data-api touchstart.dropdown.data-api'  , toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
       .on('keydown.dropdown.data-api touchstart.dropdown.data-api', toggle + ', [role=menu]' , Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
});
```

Should be,

```
$(function () {
  $('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
  $('body').on('click.dropdown touchstart.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
       .on('click.dropdown.data-api touchstart.dropdown.data-api'  , toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
       .on('keydown.dropdown.data-api touchstart.dropdown.data-api', toggle + ', [role=menu]' , Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
});

}( window.jQuery );
```

Comment: This solved my problem to an extent. Thing is, I still had two add both the unminified and the minified versions, leaving out one of them didn't help. And also, the dropdowns didn't work on phone.

Comment: You declaring the same script twice is my point.  Its like writing the functions twice just for fun. You don't need two included...you shouldn't have two included.\

Comment: That's not possible its the same script.

Comment: Okay, so here is this. I added the unminified versions alone like you said. But the mobile issue comes up. On clicking the dropdown in the navbar, I get the two options but clicking one of them toggles and closes it.

Comment: Oh right so your saying just removing the scripts didn't fix it.  It makes sense that it didn't because all you were doing is defining the scripts twice.  As for the mobile issue I'm guessing thats outside the domain of this question.

Comment: Your code helped me fix the dropdown issue, thanks a lot for that. I will try to solve the mobile issue too.

Comment: Yeah, indeed it is, responsinator shows everything is fine but my phone doesn't :P

Answer (score 1):

Okay so all of you. Though shapeshifter has been patient with me and helped me out to his best. Here is another solution to it.

Apparently, there is an issue with the latest version of Twitter Bootstrap 2.2.2 or whatever. What happens is when you use a bootstrap dropdown submenu, on touching the link from your touch devices, you do not get redirected to the link, instead the dropdown list or menu just toggles back and closes. So for time being, they asked to enter some codes and fix it (just like the above answer and many others found on github) but adding this code might sometimes disable your normal dropdown lists or give other issues. Something or the other keeps going wrong and also it doesn't work on ALL the touch devices. I have personally tried it on iPhones, Galaxies, Windows phones, Nokia, etc with the help of my friends.

So after surfing a lot of similar issues on GitHub, I found that many of them switched back to Twitter Bootstrap Version 2.0.4 which has no issues at all, neither with the dropdown nor with the touch devices. And the boostrap.js for this version works fine for all the devices without having the user to edit or make any changes.

If anyone face a similar problem, I have given you a fix for time being. Bootstrap developers are working on it. If you want the 2.0.4 version, here is the link: 
[Twitter Bootstrap 2.0.4](https://github.com/sindrenm/meteor/tree/e26672a50d033bb484876f9128d8b75be1eecc40/packages/bootstrap)

Thanks all!